# Database Tables - normalized enough?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

Here are two tables I designed for managing user accounts.

```
create table if not exists users (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  username varchar(100) not null,
  password binary(60) not null,
  first_name varchar(100) not null,
  last_name varchar(100) not null,
  role_id int unsigned not null,
  primary key(id),
  unique(username)
);

create table if not exists roles (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  role varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(id),
  unique(role)
);
```

I think I need to normalize the first table, e.g. splitting the first table into some sort of user_info(first_name, last_name, ...) and account (username, password, role_id). The problem I have is that I am very uncertain of why I need to do this, as I can't really explain why it isn't in 3NF.

**EDIT**

A user can only have exactly one role (admin, poweruser, user).

Comment: I don't think there's an appropriately-objective answer to this question. My personal opinion is there's no benefit to normalizing the `users` table you've got there.

Comment: @djacobson: One of the reasons for developing a formal data model is to provide an objective basis for making judgments about table structures. (The relational model of data is a formal data model.) Based on the information provided, the table "users" is in 5NF. No need for opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to separate the user information and account information if a user can have multiple accounts or an account can have multiple users.  If the user-to-account relationship is always 1-to-1, then you're normalized as is.

Occasionally it makes sense to separate out columns in a 1-to-1 relationship if the columns in the second table will be used rarely. However, in this case, it seems as though both tables would always be populated, so there's nothing to be gained by separating those columns.

Comment: you also have to normalize other cases: Cities for example, this is a 1:1 relationship, but normaly there are more users in a database, then cities.

Comment: @Thomas Berger: I don't see how people-to-cities could possibly be a 1:1 relationship.  Almost by definition, one city contains multiple people.

Comment: sry, you are right, don't know how i come to this, maybe i should got, catch some sleep, but: So much code, so less time ....

Answer (score 2):

Decompose the users table further only if it's allowable to have a user id and username without a corresponding first name and last name. Otherwise it looks like your tables are already in 5NF.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a SQL Expert, but this tables looks very normalized to me. You should normalize a table to save space:

If you have a column, like `role` and you have 20 users with 5 roles, each roles uses 10byte, you will have `20 * 10bytes = 200bytes`.

But if you normalize the table, as you have done it already, you will only need `5 * 10bytes = 50bytes` for the role name, `5 * 1byte = 5byte` for the id in the role table and `20 * 1byte = 20byte` for the id in the user table.

- `200bytes` not normalized
- `50bytes + 20bytes + 5bytes = 75bytes` in normalized form.

This is only a very incomplete and basic calculation to show the background.

Comment: Normalization is about integrity, accurate representation of data. It has nothing to do with saving space.